# Is it possible to disable vault with ansible playbook?

Tags: testing, ansible, ansible-vault

For automated testing purposes, I'd like to disable the vault when executing ansible-playbook so that the encrypted variables are overridden in the tests.

I've seen the `--ask-vault-pass` but not the contrary i.e. `--no-vault-pass` or the like.

The [ansible settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) don't specify an environment variable to do so.

Comment: I dont think so there is such option but you can pass a fixed vars for tests using `--vault-id` option

Comment: yes and then ansible is searching a password file ; if it cannot decrypt vault files, it fails.

Comment: You could use a special configuration file for testing purposes with the vault information deliberatly excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a special configuration file for your tests where the vault information is deliberatly excluded and tell ansible to use this configuration file when running your test playbooks:

```
ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/my/special.cfg ansible-playbook testplaybook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What we did is having a `test` dir (with all the test stuffs) and we're running tests from here (the ansible.cfg is at the root dir) with shunit2.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for structure separation by enviroments, something like this:

```
├── ansible.cfg               # check below.
├── inventories               # directory to group all hosts and variables.
│   ├── production            # "environment" directory as we discussed before.
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── appserver
│   │   │   │   ├── vars.yml
│   │   │   │   └── vault.yml # encrypted sensitive data.
│   │   │   └── proxyserver
│   │   │       ├── vars.yml
│   │   │       └── vault.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   ├── staging
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   ├── appserver
│   │   │   │   ├── vars.yml
│   │   │   │   └── vault.yml # encrypted sensitive data.
│   │   │   └── proxyserver
│   │   │       ├── vars.yml
│   │   │       └── vault.yml
│   │   └── inventory
│   └── development
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   ├── appserver
│       │   │   └── vars.yml  # no need to encrypt for local development.
│       │   └── proxyserver
│       │       └── vars.yml
│       └── inventory
├── site.yml
├── books                     # group all the playbooks under same directory.
│   ├── appserver.yml
│   └── proxyserver.yml
├── roles
│   └── app
└── roles.galaxy              # separate contributed roles
    └── author.proxy
```

**Continue here:**
https://steyeu.co/posts/ansible-project-layout-for-multistage-environments-based-on-best-practice/#the-suggested-way

Comment: Yes it is kind of what we did with a test dir and test inventory.